# For loop in Powershell to execute x different server restarts

Tags: powershell, for-loop

I was trying to execute x different server restarts with a PowerShell script, but as soon as it hits my for loop it just ends and I don't know where I made the mistake.

Code:

```
$x = Read-Host "How much you want to restart"

for ($i=0; $i -eq $x; $i++)
{
    $name = read-host "Enter Servername" $i "to restart"
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $name -wait
    write-host "Server" $name "restarded"
}
```

Edit: thx to the answer I corrected the `$i++` but still it does end immediately after the number is entered.

Comment: `i++` --> `$i++` ?

Comment: try for ($i=1; $i -eq $x ; $i++) instead.  Your code starts counting from 0 whereas humans start from 1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[arco444](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3115685/arco444)'s answer should fix your problem. However, maybe it's more interesting to write your code like this:

```
$serverList = @()

Do {
    $name = read-host "Enter Servername to restart"
    if ($name) {
        $serverList += $name
    }
} While ($name)

Foreach ($server in $serverList) {
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $server -wait
    write-host "Server $server restarded"
}
```

This will keep asking for a servername, until you provide none. Then it will go ahead and restart the servers.

Or:

```
Do {
    $name = read-host "Enter Servername to restart"
    if ($name) {
        Restart-Computer -ComputerName $name -wait
        write-host "Server $name restarded"
    }
} While ($name)
```

Comment: Thx for the quick answer, this looks way better, the only real thing is i can't analyze this to 100% correctly what makes it sadly not useable for me as i have to add more now.

Comment: If you mean you want to restart a server every time you enter a servername, you could do it like this. (I'll edit it into my answer)

Comment: This is handy and i can follow it more easily but i think i got the clue now. I didn't understand how arrays and how foreach is handled in powershell thats why i got some problems with this.

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to encapsulate the rebooting code separately from the gathering of COMPUTERNAMEs. This would make it possible for the list of computers to be created from a script prompting for names or any other method.

When you are confident that the correct computers will be rebooted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Restart-Computer` cmdlet.

=== Do-Reboot.ps1

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [string[]]$ComputerName
)

foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
    Write-Information "reboot $Computer"
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $Computer -Wait -WhatIf
}
```

Then, it can be used:

```
Do-Reboot -ComputerName SERVER1,SERVER2,SERVER3
```

If you want to see something on the console for each reboot, use:

```
Do-Reboot -ComputerName SERVER1,SERVER2,SERVER3 -InformationAction Continue
```

If you have the list of servers in a text file, this could be used.

```
Do-Reboot -ComputerName $(Get-Content -Path '.\rebootlist.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [@Michael B.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092885/9902555) to improve your code, but below you'll find the explanation why your code doesn't work as expected.

---

Your script will never enter the `for` loop due to incorrect condition.

Here you expect to execute the command block when `$i` is equal to `$x`:

```
for ($i=0; $i -eq $x; $i++)
```

As you initialize `$i` with the value `0`, it'll check that the condition is false and never execute command block.

If you want the command block to be executed x times, your loop should look like:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $x; $i++) {
  # command block
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `-ne` instead of `-lt`.

#### Examples to check:

---

#### Working version

```
$x = 5
for ($i=0; $i -lt$x; $i++) {$i}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

---

#### Non-working version

```
$x = 5
for ($i=0; $i -eq $x; $i++) {$i}
```

Output empty

Comment: aaah allright i see thank you for the reply and the lifting answer